# Is it possible to get the required mathematica code from wolfram alpha input?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

It is very easy to get an out put in wolfram alpha if the input is very complicated and mathematica coding giving some problem. So is it possible to convert an wolfram alpha input to a standard Mathematica code then it will be very helpful for beginners

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. An example of input and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: Do you mean this? https://blog.wolfram.com/2016/12/12/launching-wolframalpha-open-code/